# Was the Brady Bunch the first blended family on TV?

Tags: the-brady-bunch

*The Brady Bunch* first aired in the USA in 1969. It featured a widow and a widower merging their families after marrying each other.

Was this the first depiction of a blended family (parents and children) on television?

---

Roommate situations, like *Three's Company* or *The Odd Couple*, wouldn't be considered blended families since there aren't children involved.

Comment: Do you mean "the first blended family on TV in the United States" or anywhere in the world?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**No.** Although *Brady* was widely known as the first example (even Florence Henderson [called it that](http://abcnews.go.com/Entertainment/florence-henderson-wished-carol-brady-had-job/blogEntry?id=17147030)), [***The Danny Thomas Show***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Danny_Thomas_Show) (AKA *Make Room For Daddy*) already featured a blended family in **1957**, and was probably the very first one to do it on American TV.

Originally a show about a married couple called Danny and Margaret (Danny Thomas & Jean Hagen) with 2 children, the storyline had to change when Hagen left the show in season 4. So her character was killed off and soon replaced with that of Kathy (Marjorie Lord), a young widow with a daughter; Danny eventually married Kathy and adopted her daughter in season 5, which aired on CBS in 1957.